# How to I prove that this difference is greater than some number

Tags: calculus

Let $f$ be a function defined on $[0,1]$ by

$$f(x) = { 0, \text{ if } x = 0} $$
$$f(x) = { x \sin \frac 1 x , \text{ if } 0 < x \leq 1} $$
I was to show that $|f(x_2)-f(x_1)|>n$, for some number $n$ and thus prove the polygonal segments on $f$ does not approach zero and thus not rectifiable. I know the alternating sine function has something to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

Note that for any $k\in\mathbb{N}$ it is

$$f\left(\frac{2}{(4k+1)\pi} \right)=4k+1$$ and

$$f\left(\frac{1}{2k\pi} \right)=0.$$

Comment: So that gives me in a way the least and greatest values, but I'm not sure how to implement this for arbitrary f(x1) and f(x2) and into the difference that I want to obtain

Comment: I think intuitively we have that the highest difference will be 4k+1 and 4k+1 has no bound and therefore this difference goes to infinity?

Comment: There is no highest difference. Take a partition $\{0,1/(4n+1)\pi,1/2n\pi,1\}.$ Get the total variation of this partition. What can you say about the supremum on $n?$

Answer (score 0):

Select $x_1$so that $f(x_1)=0$ (use periodicity of $\sin x$ ) and select $x_2$ so that $f(x_2) \neq 0$ .Using periodicity of $ \sin x $ , this difference is reached infinitely often.